# Passing Class.forName through generic type class parameter

Tags: java, generics, javafx-2

I am trying to make universal TableView in JavaFx for all of my models in application:

```
    Class c = Class.forName(fullClassNames.get(itemNum));
    table.getItems().clear();
    Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields(); 
    for (int i=0; i < fields.length; i++){
         table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn(fields[i].getName()));
         ((TableColumn)table.getColumns().get(table.getColumns().size()-1)).setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<???, ???>(fields[i].getName()));
                        }
```

and I don't know how can I pass "c" (that stores my model) and field type through PropertyValueFactory like generic parameter? For example it looks like:

```
new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("lastName")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics are largely a compile time feature.

You don't have to specify the generic types at run time.

You can create

```
new PropertyValueFactory("lastName")
```

Comment: Thanks, table was created, but all my work is useless, because I had modelManager<T> that receives a model to work with... It's sad, that Java can't provide good agile for code(

Comment: I don't understand your reply.